# How to remove space for icon in MenuItem(wx.Menu) in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, menuitem

I want to remove the space for the icon on the left side of the MenuItem(wx.Menu) in wxPython.
How can I do it?

```python
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    exitMenuItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), 'Exit',
                                   "Exit the application")
    menuBar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitMenuItem)
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see [framework code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK)). Also perhaps images, showing what you have and what you you would like

Comment: Code example added